# Hamming Distance Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine $n$ islands, each of which has a $n$-letter name that
uses only "0" and "1". Each $n$-letter name uses only the letters “1” and “0” corresponds to one island. For example, if $n= 3$, then 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110 and 111 are all the islands. The transportation system consists of ferries traveling back and forth between each pair of
islands that differ in exactly one letter. For instance 000 and 001 are connected since they differ by 1 letter (Hamming distance)

1. How many ferry routes are there in terms of ?

Each island desires easy access to a store, where “easy access” means there is a store on their own island or on one that they can get to with a single ferry ride.

1. What is the maximum number of stores that can be built while satisfying the restriction than no one has easy access to more than one store?
2. If we want to make sure each island has easy access to a store even if it means some will have easy access to two. What is the minimum
   number of stores needed to satisfy this condition?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154030/imaginary-sea-of-babab.  I seem to remember another related one recently as well, but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: [Related article about the problem:](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/27522/0000566.pdf;jsessionid=301593836CA5347D4B41D6CC782EE116?sequence=1) (*see bottom of page 278 and 279 where it talks about dominating numbers*) showing that for $n$ of the form $n=2^k-1$ one has $a_{0,0}(Q_n)=2^n/n+1$, but at the time of writing the paper no result is known in general for general $n$.  Of course, for small values of $n$ the numbers can be brute forced.  [See also](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103312/game-theory-guessing-a-binary-number/103366#103366).